# ERROR: array size exceeds the maximum allowed (1073741823)

Tags: performance, postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to dissolve boundaries of a table of polygons which are ST_Buffers of 5km radius and dump them into another table. The first table contains around 10 million polygons.
The table that contains the polygon is:

```
CREATE TABLE poly_5km(gid serial PRIMARY KEY, bufferType varchar, the_geog geography(POLYGON,4326) );
```

Here's the table that I want to create:

```
CREATE TABLE buffer_5km(gid serial PRIMARY KEY, bufferType varchar, the_geog geography(POLYGON,4326) );

INSERT INTO buffer_5km(gid,bufferType,the_geog) VALUES (1,'test',(SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Multi(ST_Union(ST_MakeValid(poly_5km.the_geog::geometry))))).geom::geography FROM poly_5km WHERE poly_5km.bufferType= 'test'));
```

But whenever I run the insert statement, I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR:  array size exceeds the maximum allowed (1073741823)
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Your select is consuming too much memory. What about batch the process ??

Comment: Is it about system memory or the limit on column size ? I've 16 GB RAM on my system. I've tried `ST_MemUnion` too. But it's too slow and takes forever to run.

Comment: You are loading too much try to use 64 bits or batch size process.

Comment: @AlvaroJoao what do you mean batch the process?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are trying to store more than 1GB long value. PostgreSQL objects [has 1GB limits](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/TOAST) - you cannot to change it. This limit is same on 32 or 64bit platforms. So you have to change algorithm or granularity.