# ArrayField max size?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I'm going to use Django's ArrayField to store a pretty massive list of maybe 500-50,000 items. They're short Ids like `283974892598353920`, but I'm worried about hitting some upper limit. Are there any limits for Django's Postgres ArrayField?

Comment: from the doc, it states that *However, the current implementation ignores any supplied array size limits, i.e., the behavior is the same as for arrays of unspecified length.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [size/length limitation of array type in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765983/size-length-limitation-of-array-type-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your IDs are made of digits exclusively and stay below 2^63 (
9223372036854780000), I suggest an array of `bigint` as data type: `bigint[]`. That occupies 8 bytes per element (plus a little overhead).

Your given example *283974892598353920* is roughly 2^60 and well within that range.

The only relevant [Postgres limit](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/limits.html) is the maximum field size of 1 GB, allowing roughly 2^60 elements. *50,000* isn't even close.

Related:

- [ERROR: array size exceeds the maximum allowed (1073741823)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38288436/error-array-size-exceeds-the-maximum-allowed-1073741823)

Still, consider sets (tables) instead of huge arrays if you want to do any kind of queries on the data. Performance deteriorates for huge arrays.